# Confusion Matrix interpretation data perfectly balanced

Tags: nlp, classification, bert-language-model, confusion-matrix, transformer-model

I have trained a transformer based classifier with 2 classes (0,1) reaching a 91 % accuracy on a perfectly balanced dataset. I printed out the confusion matrix on validation data after had tuned the threshold on them and those are the results but they are perfectly balanced. Makes sense in your opinion?

```
09:29:30 root INFO:*** EVALUATION ON VALIDATION DATA ***
09:29:30 root INFO:AUC: 0.9708
09:29:30 root INFO:Tuned Threshold: 0.3104
09:29:31 root INFO:Matthews Correlation Coefficient computed after applying the tuned/selected threshold : 0.8230210619188743
09:29:31 root INFO:Accuracy: 91.15%
09:29:32 root INFO:--Classification report for VAL DATA--
09:29:32 root INFO:              precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.91      0.91      0.91     88406
          1       0.91      0.91      0.91     88406

   accuracy                           0.91    176812
  macro avg       0.91      0.91      0.91    176812
weighted avg       0.91      0.91      0.91    176812

        pred:0  pred:1
true:0   80583    7823
true:1    7823   80583
```

Thanks for the advice.

UPDATE:

confusion matrix on test set using the same threshold:

```
        pred:0  pred:1
true:0   81714    9968
true:1    9612   82070
```

Comment: Did you use the built-in `sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix` or just try to implement it yourself?

Comment: the built-in one

Comment: It is weird! How many samples does the validation set contain? how much are 1s and 0s?

Comment: I kept a perfect ratio 1:1 so Counter({0: 88406, 1: 88406})

Comment: Now I did the test keeping the same threshold tuned on validation data and on test set I have this confusion matrix : 
             pred:0  pred:1
true:0   81714    9968
true:1    9612   82070

Comment: Don't you think makes sense having a total equal confusion matrix since I tuned the classification threshold on them?

Comment: Did you check for any inconsistency in the confusion matrix? The summation for example

Comment: you mean to match the 0 and 1 in the input val data right?

Comment: IN that case they are correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246153/discussion-between-meti-and-chiara).